# What is non-thread-safety for?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, language-agnostic, thread-safety

There are a lot of articles and discussions explaining why it is good to build thread-safe classes. It is said that if multiple threads access e.g. a field at the same time, there can only be some bad consequences. So, what is the point of keeping **non** thread-safe code? I'm focusing mostly on .NET, but I believe the main reasons are not language-dependent.

E.g. .NET static fields are not thread-safe. What would be the result *if they were* thread-safe by default? (without a need to perform "manual" locking). What are the benefits of using (actually defaulting to) non-thread-safety?

One thing that comes to my mind is performance (more of a guess, though). It's rather intuitive that, when a function or field doesn't need to be thread-safe, it shouldn't be. However, the question is: what for? Is thread-safety just an additional amount of code you always need to implement? In what scenarios can I be 100% sure that e.g. a field won't be used by two threads at once?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Writing thread-safe code:

1. Requires more skilled developers
2. Is harder and consumes more coding efforts
3. Is harder to test and debug
4. Usually has bigger performance cost

But! Thread-safe code is not always needed. If you can be sure that some piece of code will be accessed by only one thread the list above becomes huge and unnecessary overhead. It is like renting a van when going to neighbor city when there are two of you and not much luggage.

Comment: But when can you definitely say that a DLL will never use threading? What about clients, who'd like to experiment with your library? Should one make all public methods thread-safe? Regarding the van: some people like to boast. :)

Comment: @rook: remember, if it's a good library you don't have to care about how it implements things: it should never give you access to things that are thread-unsafe unless it very carefully marks them for you.

Comment: @rook: regarding clients experimenting with their library, unless its explicitly documenting that a method is thread-safe, its safe to assume its not. Clients assume the responsibility of maintaining thread-safety when using your classes.

Comment: @rook right. if thread safety is not declared explicitly assume there is none. the thing is that there are different levels of thread safety: method can be thread/not safe, while class is. class can be safe/not while the library is (you can create several instances), sometime the whole library is not thread safe. but you have other options, like creating several app domains.

Comment: @rook: Library code should ideally **never** use any form of global variables/global state. (This includes euphemisms like "singletons".) If it needs to, you should always protect them with locks, in case the caller is threaded. But often this isn't even enough, since the caller might have 2 different components (possibly libraries themselves) which each assume they have exclusive control of your library's internal state. So just **don't use global variables in libraries**. Period.

Answer (score 12):

Thread safety comes with costs - you need to lock fields that might cause problems if accessed simultaneously.

In applications that have no use of threads, but need high performance when every cpu cycle counts, there is no reason to have safe-thread classes.

Comment: What kind of problems are these? What happens if two threads perform only read operations on a field?

Comment: @rook: If two threads perform read operations on a field, they will read the value of the field. Now if both threads say modify the field simultaneously, you might have problems.

Answer (score 5):

> So, what is the point of keeping non thread-safe code?

Cost. Like you assumed, there usually is a penalty in performance.

Also, writing thread-safe code is more difficult and time consuming.

Answer (score 5):

Thread safety is not a "yes" or "no" proposition. The meaning of "thread safety" depends upon context; does it mean "concurrent-read safe, concurrent write unsafe"? Does it mean that the application just might return stale data instead of crashing? There are many things that it can mean.

The main reason not to make a class "thread safe" is the cost. If the type won't be accessed by multiple threads, there's no advantage to putting in the work and increase the maintenance cost.

Answer (score 3):

Writing threadsafe code is painfully difficult at times.  For example, simple lazy loading requires two checks for '== null' and a lock.  It's really easy to screw up.

**[EDIT]**

I didn't mean to suggest that threaded lazy loading was particularly difficult, it's the "Oh and I didn't remember to lock that first!" moments that come fast and hard once you think you're done with the locking that are really the challenge.

Comment: It also is slow. THigns must be volatile so the compiler does not optimize access out. Volatile means cache flushes. Basically the CPU procesing gets a LOT slower.

Comment: @TomTom: absolutely, I'm just giving my main reason for not doing things in parallel all the time.  Your average consumer isn't worried too much about speed unless they notice it, which is pretty unlikely for most applications today.

Comment: Ah, nice ;) I Wish I would have this luxury - working with a LOT of data or very time critical data turns my viewpoint.

Comment: Yup, while I was at a research joint we definitely cared about speed because a few extra CPU cycles meant a few more days of processing time.  Now I build applications and the processing time only matters when it interrupts the UI painting. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are situations where "thread-safe" doesn't make sense. This consideration is in addition to the higher developer skill and increased time (development, testing, and runtime all take hits).

For example, `List<T>` is a commonly-used non-thread-safe class. If we were to create a thread-safe equivalent, how would we implement `GetEnumerator`? Hint: there is no good solution.

Comment: However, still some exist. What is wrong about such implementations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "still some exist." The only way to have truly thread-safe data structures is to make them immutable.

Comment: In fact, "still" is to strike out. What I mean is that some solutions exist, which seem to deal with the thread-safety issue effectively. Maybe they are not "good" as you say.

Comment: @rook: What I mean is that some classes (e.g., `List<T>`) cannot actually be made thread-safe. You can create other thread-safe collections (such as `ConcurrentQueue<T>`), or choose to make it immutable, but you cannot have a thread-safe `List<T>` that has the same semantics as a non-thread-safe `List<T>`.

Comment: @StephenCleary: Indexed operations on `List<T>` cannot be meaningfully threadsafe if there is a possibility that items may be removed between the time one determines the index of the item one wants, and the time one acts upon that index.  One could, however, have useful thread-safe subsets of `List<T>`'s functionality including e.g. all members that don't remove items, or including `Add`, `Remove`, `RemoveAt(0)`, `Item(0).Get`, and `GetEnumerator`, but no other indexed operations (the lack of a `Try` method to read item 0 would be irksome, but not insurmountable).

Answer (score 2):

> So, what is the point of keeping non thread-safe code?

By allowing for code that isn't thread safe you're leaving it up to the **programmer to decide what the correct level of isolation is.**

As others have mentioned this allows for complexity reduction and improved performance.

Rico Mariani wrote two articles entitled "[Putting your synchronization at the correct level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/04/24/582643.aspx)" and
[Putting your synchronization at the correct level -- solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2006/05/03/589327.aspx) that have a nice example of this in action.

In the article he has a method called `DoWork()`. In it he calls other classes `Read`  twice `Write` twice and then `LogToSteam`.

`Read`, `Write`, and `LogToSteam` all shared a lock and were thread safe. This is good except for the fact that because `DoWork` was also thread safe all the synchronizing work in each `Read`, `Write` and `LogToSteam` was a complete waste of time.

This is all related to the nature Imperative Programming. Its side effects cause the need for this.

However if you had an development platform where applications could be expressed as pure functions where there were no dependencies or side effects then it would be possible to create applications where the threading was managed without developer intervention.

Answer (score 2):

Turn this question on its head.

In the early days of programming there was no Thread-Safe code because there was no concept of threads. A program started, then proceeded step by step to the end. Events? What's that? Threads? Huh?

As hardware became more powerful, concepts of what types of problems could be solved with software became more imaginative and developers more ambitious, the software infrastructure became more sophisticated. It also became much more top-heavy. And here we are today, with a sophisticated, powerful, and in some cases unnecessarily top-heavy software ecosystem which includes threads and "thread-safety".

I realize the question is aimed more at application developers than, say, firmware developers, but looking at the whole forest does offer insights into how that one tree evolved.

Answer (score 0):

`So, what is the point of keeping non thread-safe code?`

The rule of thumb is to avoid locking as much as possible. The Ideal code is re-entrant and thread safe with out any locking. But that would be utopia.

Coming back to reality, a `good` programmer tries his level best to have a sectional locking as opposed to locking the entire context. An example would be to lock few lines of code at a time in various routines than locking everything in a function.

So Also, one has to refactor the code to come up with a design that would minimize the locking if not get rid of it in entirity.

e.g. consider a `foobar()` function that gets new data on each call and uses `switch() case`  on a type of data to changes a node in a tree. The locking can be mostly avoided (if not completely) As each case statement would touch a different node in a tree. This may be a more specific example but i think it elaborates my point.